# Reading of Swift's On Poetry correctly

Tags: pronunciation, rhymes, seventeenth-century-english

Jonathan Swift wrote once that

> So, naturalists observe, a flea
> Hath smaller fleas that on him prey;
> And these have smaller still to bite 'em;
> And so proceed ad infinitum.

You can see that *to bite 'em* shall rhyme with *infinitum*. What is the rhyming phoneme here? Is it *to b[ai]t 'em* / *infin[ai]tum*, or *to b[i]t 'em* / *infin[i]tum*(?

Comment: I choose: to b[ai]t 'em/infin[ai]tum.     [And here I though you were going to ask about how "flea" and "prey" rhyme].

Comment: Listen to https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2wEwkzanqPc

Comment: @GEdgar `flea` and `prey` are more or less easy.

Comment: *in* like the preposition; *fin* like the fish appendage; *item* like your grocery list. That's pretty much how *infinitum* is pronounced.

Comment: **MODERATOR NOTE::** Please do not use code markup to specify [mentions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Use%E2%80%93mention_distinction). We set mentions in italic, not in some funky font that pretends to be a crazy old-fashioned Courier typewriter written on funky blue paper in faded ink :)

Comment: Don't forget that the 17C was a long time ago, that Swift was being less than entirely serious (because of the contraction "bite 'em") and that Swift was Irish. The intended pronunciation could have been, and probably was, affected by all three of these factors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last two lines rhyme on /ˈaɪtəm/.

The pronunciation traditionally used in English for the Latin word *infinitum* ends in /aɪtəm/ because /aɪ/ is the English "long i" sound, and vowel letters in Latin words were traditionally pronounced as the English "long vowel" sounds in stressed second-to-last syllables when the vowel letter is followed by only a single consonant.

Similarly, we find /aɪ/ in the pronunciations of *sinus, virus, minus* as English words.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traditional_English_pronunciation_of_Latin